# Should naive, but technically correct questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

During close review process I came across [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10936/has-any-government-commisioned-a-study-of-whether-its-people-are-better-or-worse) and I did not know what to do (I skipped it): it sounds kind of silly (thus many downvotes), but it seems to be technically correct (it is about governments and asks for a study example, so it is clearly not broad).

Currently, it has 4 close votes:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or
>   discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not
>   appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments,
>   policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

It also has a good answer explaining why the requested study cannot happen.

Personally, I don't think the close reason is correctly applied to this question and I am wondering what should we do with this kind of questions?

**Question:** Should naive, but technically correct questions be closed?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How do we find out that the user is banned network wide for 10 years? I don't dispute the veracity of it but don't know where it is displayed?

Comment: It's on [the user's profile page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/7483/d-j-sims) @SleepingGod:  "This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Oct 17 '26 at 23:59."

Answer (score 2):

If you don't think the question is too broad, not too opinion-based, and genuinely seeking information, not a duplicate, and on-topic, then I wouldn't vote to close even if it does seem stupid.

Stack exchange exists to provide answers to questions, even if they are naive or silly seeming questions.

Comment: Obviously, sites differ, but I frequently find that, at least on SFF, seemingly "naive stupid" questions are actually quite interesting and often, surprisingly deep, from the point of view of a genuine subject matter expert (i.e, a bunch of people with some tag answers will denigrate a question but someone with the gold tag badge will find it   interesting).